# Как узнать свой текущий онлайн?

Tags: ssh

Доброй ночи. 
Вопрос может показаться некорректным:)
Есть хостинг, доступ через `ssh`.

1. Как узнать кто онлайн в данный момент на сайте по ssh?
   или это невозможно сделать командой и нужен счетчик.
   Просто если сервер бодро пишет логи, то почему нельзя посмотреть, кто (IP) вот прямо сейчас онлайн...?
2. Нашел команду "w" но она не работает :(
3. `netstat` туда же `command not found`
   Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `w` — обычно алиас на `who` [(1)](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/who-invocation.html).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте команду

```
pinky
```

Ещё можно проверить значения - SSH_CONNECTION, SSH_CLIENT переменной среды